# Compile Error: Method or data member not found - Calling sub

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting error in VBA code -
Compile Error: Method or data member not found

I am just calling a sub form another sub
Error at this line:

```
Sub CopyRiskData(scenario As String)
```

Highlighted area:

```
Set pca = ThisWorkbook

Sub CopyEODOnlyRisk(dayIntra As String)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RISK").Range("dateINTRA").Value = dayIntra
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RISK").Range("dateEOD").Calculate
    CopyRiskData ("EOD")
End Sub

Sub CopyRiskData(scenario As String)
    Dim pca As Workbooks
    Dim riskInput As Worksheet
    Dim dNum As String

    Set pca = ThisWorkbook
    Set riskInput = pca.Sheets("RISK")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
Dim pca As Workbook
```

not

```
Dim pca As Workbooks
```

Also, call the sub with

```
CopyRiskData "EOD"
```